# DataGrid binding crashes UWP app on Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, datagrid, uwp

I am creating an application with Xamarin using the shared definition, and my application should run on Android and as an UWP app. This App needs to show a DataGrid with bindable values and for this I am using the [Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid](https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid). I had followed the sample showed in DataGrid's repository, and it works very well on Android, but I am having an issue when I try to run as a UWP app. The issue is that, when I run as a UWP app with a populated List and try to binding this list on the DataGrid, the app crashes, showing this Exception:

```
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
at Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer`2.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
at Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer`2.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
at Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
at Xamarin.Forms.Plat"
```

As I had said this exception only occur on UWP, and only happens when this List is populate. The list is create in this way:

```
private List<TableValue> _tableValues;

public List<TableValue> TableValues
{
   get { return _tableValues; }
   set
   {
      TableValues= value;
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TableValues));
   }
}

private List<TableValue> CreateTableValues()
{
    return new List<TableValue>{
        new TableValue{Val1="", Val2="", Val3="", Val4="", Val5="", Val6="", Val7=""}
    };
}

public async Task PopulateItems()
{
    _tableValues = CreateTableValues();
    UpdateProperty();
}
```

This list is create inside of the MVVM class of the View.
The DataGrid element is create in the View in that way:

```
private ScrollView CreateTable()
{
   table = new DataGrid();
   table.Columns.Clear();
   table.Columns.AddRange(CreateColumns());
   table.SelectionEnabled = true;
   table.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
   table.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("TableValues"));
   table.HeaderBackground = Color.FromHex("#D4D0C8");
   table.HeaderFontSize = 18;
   table.HeaderTextColor = Color.FromHex("#08098F");

   StackLayout tableStack = new StackLayout
   {
       BackgroundColor = Color.White,
       HeightRequest = 850,
       VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
   };
   tableStack.Children.Add(table);

   var scroll = new ScrollView
   {
       BackgroundColor = Color.White,
       Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5),
       Content = tableStack,
       Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal,
       HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
       VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
   };

   return scroll;
}
```

I searched to find a possible solution for this problem, but I was not able to find any solution, since the questions using this DataGrid in Xamarin are few common.

Comment: I am surprised you are not getting a stack overflow with: `set
   {
      TableValues= value;
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TableValues));
   }` since that setter will call the setter again, and again, and again, etc.. Not sure if this will help the issue described, but try `_tableValues = value;` instead.

Comment: @jgoldberger I changed that line following your answer and I noticed the problem you described, but the main problem about the table still happens.

Comment: Then I would suggest filing an issue on the repo for the DataGrid you are using to reach out to the package authors.

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin.Forms.UWP nesting a ListView inside of a ScrollView is not supported. Thats the reason why you're crashing. See more on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52349).